# Unhelpful 'Please provide a MCVE' comments

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users

After spending some time on less busy SE sites, I checked in on Stack Overflow to see if I could answer some questions. First click, I stumbled upon this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219489/how-to-pattern-this-example-in-c

I agree, this question was not of great quality to put it mildly. However, I think the OP was genuinely trying to ask a question, and might revise his question now that it's put on hold. However, **before** such questions are put on hold, it seems that more experienced users are **extremely eager** to downvote it and comment on it with in an unsympathetic, annoyed manner. I have seen this happening quite often, and I wonder,

- Is this considered as undesirable behaviour?
- Could measures be taken, such as removing downvotes (resetting 'upvotes' to 0) when the questions are put on hold, or having a *'did you mean to flag this question?'*-suggestion when commenting or downvoting a new, unanswered question?

EDIT: In response to answers/comments: what is the advantage of posting fairly rude, annoyed comments over just flagging it? Admittedly, this example given might not be a great one, but I've seen it happening too on users who were just struggling on how to write their question.

Comment: Usually they aren't unhelpful, but exactly what they're saying.

Comment: I agree some new users have unfortunate experiences. But consider that Stack Overflow gets 7,000+ new questions a day. Quickly downvoting and closing content that doesn't fulfill the quality standards is often simply self-defense. The onus is on the asker to ask a decent question from the get go.

Comment: After reading this meta post I was expecting to find a mediocre question with a handful of downvotes, not a terrible POS question that isn't worth even trying to save.  If the author wants to fix it into a real question, they can.  It's almost certainly not worth anyone else's time to try to help them by the looks of it though.

Comment: The comments weren't rude.  The users that commented were taking time out of their day to help this user ask a better question.  In my opinion they're wasting their time, but nothing about their comments are rude at all.

Comment: Help vampire.  "Here are my requirements [x y and z]. How do I do it?"  Questions like this are not welcome here.  Coddling vampires who post them is not warranted.  The sooner they understand what is and is not an acceptable question the better.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How hard the OP was trying doesn't affect how you should vote on a post.  You should vote based on the quality of the post, not based on any qualities of the author of that post.

If the user really is trying then they'll be able to take the feedback that they've been given and improve their question.  The feedback on the question's quality shouldn't be held back; that's only harming the author's ability to improve it.

We most certainly don't want to remove downvotes when a question is put on hold.  It being put on hold doesn't mean that the user's who evaluated the post earlier were incorrect that it wasn't useful.  In fact, that it was closed indicates that they were almost certainly *correct* in their feedback.  We also don't want to do anything to discourage people from downvoting open questions.  Plenty of open questions merit downvotes.